# Appium Unable to Switch from NativeApp to WebView in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

I have been stuck with an issue from long time unable to resolve and in need of help badly. I have an android apk file, after launching the app, it shows the Webview of the website. I am unable to switch from Native App to Webview after launching the App.

I see 2 Context available (Native and Webview) but I am not able to switch to WebView, it fails saying "*message":"ChromeDriver ready for new sessions*". Below is the error message when I attempt to switch. I verified ChromeDriver in Appium, it is same as Chromeversion and Appium is v4 latest

```
Error in switching Context : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Did not get a valid response object. Object was: {"value":{"build":{"version":"85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689})"},"message":"ChromeDriver ready for new sessions.","os":{"arch":"x86_64","name":"Windows NT","version":"10.0.17763"},"ready":true}}
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at MobileDriver.SwithContextToWebView(AppiumDriver`1 driver, String context) in C:\Automation\Src\Common\MobileDriver.cs:line 656
```

Below is my desired Capabilities

```
        private static AppiumOptions SetCapability(MobileDriverConfig config)
        {
            AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions();
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("automationName", config.AutomationName);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "Android");
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", config.PlatformName);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("platformVersion", config.PlatformVersion);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, config.SystemOs);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("udid", config.DeviceId);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", config.AppPackage);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("appActivity", config.AppActivity);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("chromeBundleId", config.ChromeBundleId);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("ensureWebviewsHavePages", config.EnsureWebviewsHavePages);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("webviewDevtoolsPort", config.WebviewDevtoolsPort);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverUseSystemExecutable", config.ChromedriverUseSystemExecutable);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("enableWebviewDetailsCollection", config.EnableWebviewDetailsCollection);
            capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("fullContextList", true);
            }
```

Below is what I am using for Context Switching

```
    public void SwitchToContext(ViewType type)
    {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
               var driver = (AppiumDriver<IWebElement>)MDriver; // this is already initialized
               System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> allContexts = driver.Contexts;   // returns 2 Context [Native_APP, WEBVIEW_packageName]
                   foreach (string context in allContexts)
                   {
                       Logger.Debug("Context Name: " + context);
                       switch (type)
                       {
                           case ViewType.Native:
                               if (context.Contains("NATIVE"))
                               {
                                   driver.Context = context;   // Native Switch works fine
                               }
                               break;
    
                           case ViewType.Webview:
                               if (context.Contains("WEBVIEW"))
                               {
                                 driver.Context = context;  // Webview switch errors out
                               }
                               break;
                       }
                   }
            }
```

below is how I am Initializing my driver

```
var driver = new AndroidDriver<IWebElement>(new Uri("http://" + config.Server + ":"
                            + config.Port + "/wd/hub/"), SetCapability(config), new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0));
```

Please help to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using Appium Local Service

```
AppiumLocalService _appiumLocalService = new AppiumServiceBuilder().UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
_appiumLocalService.Start();

var appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "Android");
appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "7.1");
_driver = new AndroidDriver<AppiumWebElement>(_appiumLocalService, appiumOptions);
```

Make sure you dispose of the service after your test

```
_appiumLocalService.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the chrome version in the used device? it should match the version of the chrome driver pointed by Appium. Check this link for more information about the chrome driver, after you download the suitable version you should add chromedriverExecutable Capability

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/appium/appium-chromedriver/master/config/mapping.json

This works for me:

```
AppiumOptions appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, 
        "Android");
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, 
        "8.1");
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName, 
        "UiAutomator2");
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, 
        "Android Device");
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, 
        "D:\\XXX.apk");
        appiumOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("chromedriverExecutable", 
        "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new 
        Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), appiumOptions);
```

Comment: My Chromedriver is of the same version used in the device, I don't know why I am getting Remote driver error, I am running on my local machine OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)

Comment: I have read before that there is a compatibility issue between chrome driver recent versions and appium , so my advice is to try to downgrade chrome and use an older version of chrome driver if you are not targeting a specific version.